# Stateful Widget Not Working Properly The Second Time It Is Navigated To

Tags: flutter

When I run the following program, it works as intended the first time I enter the BoardView widget. The second time I enter the BoardView widget, the AlertDialog for the computer player appears at the same time the human player's AlertDialog does.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  Round roundController = Round(currentIndex: -1);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("New Game",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            BoardView(roundController: widget.roundController)),
                  );
                })));
  }
}

class Round extends ChangeNotifier {
  Round({required this.currentIndex}) : handNo = 0;

  void changeTurn() {
    if (currentIndex == -1) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    } else {
      currentIndex = currentIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  int currentIndex, handNo;
}

class BoardView extends StatefulWidget {
  Round roundController;

  BoardView({Key? key, required this.roundController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BoardViewState createState() => _BoardViewState();
}

class _BoardViewState extends State<BoardView> {
  late List<String> players = ["Human", "Computer"];
  late bool showButton;

  void _playerTakesTurn() {
    if (players[widget.roundController.currentIndex] == "Human") {
      showDialogPopUp(
          context,
          "Human Player's Turn",
          "It is time for you to take your turn.",
          widget.roundController.handNo,
          widget.roundController);
    } else {
      showDialogPopUp(
          context,
          "Computer Player's Tile Placement",
          "The computer took their turn",
          widget.roundController.handNo,
          widget.roundController);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _playerTakesTurn());

    widget.roundController.addListener(_playerTakesTurn);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.roundController.removeListener(_playerTakesTurn);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[400],
    );
  }
}

Future<void> showDialogPopUp(BuildContext context, String title, String text,
    int handNo, Round roundController) {
  return showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(title: Text(title), content: Text(text), actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("OK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();

              roundController.changeTurn();

              if (handNo == 2) {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => RoundInfo(
                              roundController: roundController,
                            )));
              } else {
                roundController.handNo++;
              }
            },
          )
        ]);
      });
}

class RoundInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Round roundController;

  const RoundInfo({Key? key, required this.roundController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RoundInfo> createState() => _RoundInfoState();
}

class _RoundInfoState extends State<RoundInfo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[700],
        body: Column(children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => BoardView(
                            roundController: widget.roundController)));
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text('Proceed',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
        ]));
  }
}
```

The following image shows what occurs the first time BoardView is entered.First Time BoardView Is Entered:

[image]

And the following image shows what occurs the second time BoardView is entered through the _RoundInfoState.BoardView Entered Through The _RoundInfoState:

[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this happens because you have a `Single` Round controller in your app lifecycle, you initialized it in your first screen `Round roundController = Round(currentIndex: -1);` and every time the user goes to `BoardView` you attach a new listener to the same controller.
to solve this, simply move `Round roundController = Round(currentIndex: -1);` from `MyHomePage` to `_MyHomePageState` and fix the `widget.roundController` issue will appear

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to resolve the issue by moving `Round roundController = Round(currentIndex: -1);` from `MyHomePage` to `BoardView`. You are my saviour.

Comment: Would removing the listener from the controller or destroying the listener upon exiting _BoardViewState also solve the issue I was having?